# Send Stream in HttpResponseMessage instead of raw file

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have a requirement of sending the file stream/stream as response in webapi from odata.
Below is the code of API

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDocumentFiles()
       {
 var tskk = context.BaseUri;
                sb.Append(context.BaseUri)
                  .Append("FILES(tNumber='")
                  .Append("1")
                  .Append("',Type='")
                  .Append("2")

                  .Append("',Application='")
                  .Append("a")
                  .Append("')/$value");
             var queryUrl = sb.ToString();
             var req = WebRequest.Create(queryUrl);
             var response = req.GetResponse();
             using (var res = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse())
             {
              Stream reader = (Stream)res.GetResponseStream();
              return reader;
             }
       }
```

but, when I run the below code using postman i am getting the exception. Any ways to send the stream of file without downloading the file to any location. So that, the clients who access this method should be able to download the file using this response.

Exception received:

```
"$id": "1",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": null,
    "InnerException": {
        "$id": "2",
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Error getting value from 'Length' on 'System.Net.ConnectStream'.",
        "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
        "StackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()",
        "InnerException": {
            "$id": "3",
            "Message": "An error has occurred.",
            "ExceptionMessage": "This stream does not support seek operations.",
            "ExceptionType": "System.NotSupportedException",
            "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.ConnectStream.get_Length()\r\n   at GetLength(Object )\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Namitha

Comment: what exception? also current code shown will not compile

Comment: I have modifed with the exception, Yes the above code doesnt compile because, i have not included Query url part. But the code now contains all the contents which required to request and respond.

Comment: Review [ask] a question and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. The example shown is incomplete and wont compile.